# Using DISTINCT on mysql database with django

Tags: python, mysql, django, distinct

I've been trying (and failing) to generate a query that omits results from a model without having to make a second database.

```
pmrs.models.LootTable

class LootTable(models.Model):
    boss = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    itemid = models.IntegerField()
    itemname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    wfflag = models.BooleanField(help_text="Set true if warforged")
```

That's the model layout. What I'm trying to get is a list of everything in the boss field, but then omit the duplicates.

I've tried various different ways, .value_list, .values, order_by.().distinct etc. but nothing seems to work.

Using the following

```
bosses = LootTable.objects.values('boss').distinct()
```

Returns

```
[{'boss': u'Thok the Bloodthirsty'}, {'boss': u'Ordos'}, {'boss': u'Paragons of the Klaxxi'}, {'boss': u'Ordos'}, {'boss': u'Spoils of Pandaria'}, {'boss': u'Spoils of Pandaria'}, {'boss': u'Galakras'}, {'boss': u'General Nazgrim'}, {'boss': u'Ordos'}, {'boss': u'Spoils of Pandaria'}, {'boss': u'Siegecrafter Blackfuse'}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

As you can see from the results it's returning duplicates.

Comment: please, add your models code, and an example that what you want as result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really should take the time to put the relevant pats of your model class in the question. Condensing it like you have may seem like saving time bit in reality it makes it harder to work out exactly what you're trying to do.

Based on what you have put,

```
q = LootTable.objects.values('boss').distinct()
```

should work fine. If it doesn't then something else is wrong somewhere.

As an aside, shouldn't a boss only have one loot table? Why do you need to do `distinct` anyway? In fact looking at the model, if I understand what you're trying to do (And there is no guarantee that I do!) I can spot quite a few issues that may bite you down the line, namely:

a) why do you have a LootTable table anyway? The same functionality could be achieved with a many-to-many foreign key between `Boss` and `Item`.

b) Why does the LootTable have both item_id and item_name on it? why not just have item be a foreign key to the `Item` model? (i.e. properly normalised data)

c) how is it a table if it only points to one `Item`? :)

Comment: I did state in the original post that I'm using mysql .distinct('boss') only works with postgresql

Comment: then the first option should still work. See my update anyway

Comment: See my edit, the results of your original option is now in the original post. Thats the models I've been given. I don't have the option to change them.

Comment: any chance you could `print bosses.query` for that example you posted?

Comment: Also, you always have the option to change them. Whoever "gave" you the models looks to be trying to store relational data in a flat file database format. Using an RDBMS. Madness. :)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `pmrs_loottable`.`boss`, `pmrs_loottable`.`itemname` FROM `pmrs_loottable` ORDER BY `pmrs_loottable`.`itemname` ASC

Comment: I think I will just have to explain to the project manager that the model is very poorly designed and figure out some way of transferring that data to a better laid out schema. Thanks for your insight Pete, it's opened my eyes a lot.